# How to send multiple axios put requests in one method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I want to send multiple PUT requests in one method but I do not know if it's possible, because all the documentation and answers on SO are only for GET requests.

```
// vue script, this is one PUT request

updateProduct() {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`
    },
  };
  axios
    .put(
      "myapihere.com" +
        this.$route.params.id,
      {
        name: this.name,
      },
      config
    )
    .then(async (res) => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
},
```

I want to add 2 more PUT requests in the `updateProduct` method. Is it possible to use Promise.all? and then how do I send the body to each corresponding URL? Appreciate all help, thank you.

Comment: yes, you can use Promise.all, the requests will be simultaneous, and add the body just like you do with one request, as the second argument (it seems) to PUT - follow the pattern you've found for multiple GET requests, the type of request (GET/PUT/POST) is irrelevant to the problem, just put the relevant body into each request as required

Answer (score 0):

```js
// vue script, this is one PUT request

updateProduct() {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
  };
  // lets say you wanna use the following data to send to 3 requests
  const allNames = ["name1", "name2", "name3"];
  // following lets say your url params that are corresponding to your eachrequests
  const allParamIds = ["11","12","13"]
  const allRequests = allNames.map((eachName, index) => {
    const currentName = eachName;
    const currentParamId = allParamsIds[index]
    const currentUrl = `myapihere.com/${currentParamId}`
    // you have to return as a promise
    return axios.put(currentUrl, body: JSON.stringify({name: currentName}), config)
  })
  // Promise.all() takes an array as argument, allRequests is an array
  Promise.all(allRequests)
   .then((response) => {
    // response will be an array
      console.log("response is", response);
   })
   .catch(err => console.error(err))
},
```

Let me know if it worked for you or not!